# What is wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

```
function moveit() {

    var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);
    var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1024);
    var newDuration = 9000

    $('#friends').animate({
      top: newTop,
      left: newLeft,
 !!! -->     width: "+="+((newTop-$('friends').css('top'))*3),
      }, newDuration, function() {
        moveit();
      });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});
```

It is supposed to make an image fly around (works).
I added the line marked with the "!!! -->" that should make the image get bigger the closer it is to the bottom of the page.

What did I do wrong?  The code doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('friends').css('top')` returns a string, you'll need to convert this to an int before you can use it to subtract from `newTop`

```
parseInt($('friends').css('top'), 10)
```

Would do the trick

Also you need to use an ID or class identifier in your jQuery selector, either `'#friends'` or `'.friends'` but I imagine you're looking for something with the ID of friends

Try this

```
width: "+="+((newTop - parseInt($('#friends').css('top'), 10))*3),
```

Comment: It still doesn't change sizes.

Comment: @DalexL - Combine @Jimmy's and @richardneililagan's answers, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you mean `$('#friends')` instead of just plain `$('friends')`? Your statement is looking for an element tag "friends" and trying to get it's `top` CSS property value.

I'd suggest you also cache the `$('friends')` selector so that you don't have to select it twice for the `.animate()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure your problem is `.css("top")` will return a string value like `100px`. You want to use `.position().top` instead to get the integer value instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in how you're getting the top position.  May not be exactly what you want, but I got it working here...

http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/YXMbh/