# Why wont IE display this correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, animation

http://jsfiddle.net/DalexL/NG6ty/

The link above shows what I'm working with.  I currently have a hot air balloon that needs to fly around the page.  It works fine in Google Chrome but doesn't even move or anything inside of IE.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this code...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940088/what-is-wrong-with-this-code)

Comment: @Neal Except I posted that question and it had no relevance to the differences between IE and GC.  @Alison What about the earlier version of IE?

Comment: I've tested that on win7 with IE9 and it works just like FF or Chrome... the only thing was that the balloon at first start moving outside my view-port, but a refresh and voilà... there it was again moving inside the view-port... You should control the movement to keep it inside the view-port at all times... (to people actually see it!)  If you've tested this in some other version of IE, let us know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
width: "+="+(newTop),
```

you should remove the comma

```
width: "+="+(newTop)
```

IE usually is more tolerant to sloppy code, but in this case was working fine for other browsers, even though the extra comma was syntactically incorrect. Removing it worked fine for IE7. I guess IE9 "forgives" this kind of syntax error

Comment: well, just for that I can say that at var newDuration = 9000, its missing a ";" at the line end ;)  (IE7 really fails with just that)

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I didn't even imagine it would be something so small!

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct in just a couple of minutes :)

Comment: "I didn't even imagine it would be something so small!" See the [Trailing Comma of Death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/)